# php Newlines vs html break

Tags: php

This code:

```
<?php
  echo "This is the first line. \n";
  echo "This is the second line.";
?>
```

Echoes out all on the same line: ("This is the first line. This is the second line.")

Shouldn't `\n` have basically the same function as `<br>` ? What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you looking at your browser's rendering of this, or the source?

Comment: No - whitespace is generally not significant in HTML. `\n` will be discarded by a browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML doesn't render \n, a \n will put a break in your HTML source code

PHP

```
<?php
echo "<p>This is the first line. \n";
echo "This is the second line.</p>";
?>
```

HTML Source

```
<p> This is the first line.
This is the second line.</p>
```

HTML

```
This is the first line. This is the second line.
```

---

PHP

```
<?php
echo "<p>This is the first line.";
echo "This is the second line.</p>";
?>
```

HTML Source

```
<p> This is the first line.This is the second line.</p>
```

HTML

```
This is the first line.This is the second line.
```

---

PHP

```
<?php
echo "<p>This is the first line. <br/>";
echo "This is the second line.</p>";
?>
```

HTML Source

```
<p> This is the first line.<br/>This is the second line.</p>
```

HTML

```
This is the first line. 
This is the second line.
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your VERY thorough answer :^)

Comment: I just love a thorough response like this.

Answer (score 3):

You mix up the output of php and the result in your browser. `\n` is newline. You may see it, when you read the source code in your browser(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in Chrome) .

But browser only render `<br>` as newline on webpage

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "This is the first line. \n";
```

Will produce a linebreak in your source, meaning the cursor is currently on the next line (the line belove the text).

```
echo "This is the second line.";
```

Will produce a single line and leave the cursor right after the text (on the same line).

```
echo "This is the second line.<br />";
```

Will produce a single line but in rendered html containing a visible linebreak. However, in the sourcecode there will be no linebreaks, so:

```
echo "Line one<br />Line two";
```

Will render two lines in html but one line in the source.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "This is the first line.", '<br />', PHP_EOL;
```

^ **HTML** code for `BR` and `ENTER`.
`ENTER` is visible in the source or `PRE` tags, or `TEXTAREA`s, or when enabled by CSS `white-space` *(etc.)* **while** `BR` is the line break in `HTML`.